# C++, функции-члены, указатели на функции

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток.
Возможно глупый вопрос, но:


Есть класс Manager.
Внутри этого класса есть код, который может сгенерировать событие.
Есть другой класс M_User(а может их будет и несколько), которые создают у себя экземпляры класса Manager и хотят указать ему свою функцию-член как обработчик некоторого события.


Учитывая, что указатель на функцию-член будет M_User1::* \ M_User2::*,
возможно ли это вовсе? Без наследования.

Comment: Как возможный ответ на мой же вопрос: template. Принимать тип создателя объекта и генерировать поле на функцию-член этого типа? Это единственный возможный вариант?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вполне можно обойтись std::function.

```
/// Тип обработчика
using handler_t = std::function<void()>;

class Manager
{
public:
    /// Установка обработчика
    void SetHandler(handler_t handler)
    {
        ///.... some actions
    }
};

class User
{
public:
    /// Установка обработчика
    void Bind()
    {
        handler_t handler = std::bind(&User::_HandlerFunction, this);
        _manager->SetHandler(std::move(handler));
    }

private:
    /// Сам обработчик
    void _HandlerFunction()
    {
        ///.... some action
    }

    Manager* _manager;  
};
```

Но, раз уж вы заикнулись о событиях, следует посмотреть в сторону boost::signals2::signal